# Storing repeated data into database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

What is a good way to store repeated varchars in a row of database.

I have lots of repeated values in some columns and feels like there is a better way to do this.

What I have in mind is something like assigning the column with an foreign key and do a join to get its value from a table called misc.

Here is a illustration of what I have in mind:
[image]

Am I on the right track? Also, if I do it this way, how would I get the values of both columns.

I'm using:
PHP 5.5,
MySQL 5.6

In "Table 1" PK is an auto increment `INT`, and FK will be the PK of "Table 2" which is `misc_id`

Comment: You should edit your question and post all the tables available including their PK, FK and PFK. Only then, users could help you figure out whats wrong with your design.

Comment: Better? Or do I need to provide more info?

Comment: If those are all the tables available then it's ok :)

Comment: Smells a lot like "Normalization", which is lauded in database worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sub-queries.

```
SELECT project_id, project_category, project_sub_category,
 (SELECT item FROM misc WHERE project_category = misc_id) AS cat,
 (SELECT item FROM misc WHERE project_sub_category = misc_id) AS sub
FROM projects
WHERE project_id = 4
```

This is the array I would get:

```
Array
(
    [project_id] => 4
    [project_category] => 1
    [project_sub_category] => 2
    [cat] => IT & Development
    [sub] => Mobile Software Development
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of both columns in your proposed design, you would do a query like:

```
SELECT cat.item, sub.item
FROM table1 prj
JOIN table2 cat ON prj.project_category = cat.misc_id
JOIN table2 sub ON prj.project_sub_category = sub.misc_id
```

Are project categories and sub-categories interchangeable?  If so, you're on the right track, just give those tables proper names.

If not, I recommend you don't go that route.  Rather than collecting all your VARCHARs into one table, make separate tables to describe different sets of values:

```
project (project_category PK/FK, project_sub_category PK/FK)
project_category (project_category PK, category_name VARCHAR)
project_sub_category (project_sub_category PK, sub_category_name VARCHAR)
```

Which you can then query with:

```
SELECT cat.category_name, sub.sub_category_name
FROM project prj
JOIN project_category cat ON prj.project_category = cat.project_category
JOIN project_sub_category sub ON prj.project_sub_category = sub.project_sub_category
```

So the structure of the query doesn't change much, but the advantage in distinguishing your categories and sub-categories is that you'll be able to add different attributes, relations and constraints in the future.

A more powerful (and complex) arrangement is to model categories and sub-categories as a hierarchy.  Starting with a table of categories like your Table 2, one could add:

```
sub_category (main_category PK/FK, sub_category PK/FK)
```

also known as a parent/child table.  In this design, you would only record the most specific category for each project.  The added complexity comes in when we want to find descendants of a given parent, for which there are techniques like [closure tables](http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html).